# Adding an image to footer for PanelGrid in PrimeFaces

Tags: image, primefaces, footer

I'm trying to add an image to a footer inside a panelGrid for Primefaces. I am using this http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/panelGrid.jsf as reference but I get this error:

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/bizSim.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID frmMain:bossMeeting:j_id2 has already been found in the view.  
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:846)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.saveView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:144)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:419)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.pdinh.bizsim.presentation.filter.RestrictPageFilter.doFilter(RestrictPageFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.pdinh.bizsim.presentation.filter.CustomCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CustomCharacterEncodingFilter.java:20)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

INFO: Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID frmMain:bossMeeting:j_id2 has already been found in the view.  
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:846)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.saveView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:144)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:419)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.pdinh.bizsim.presentation.filter.RestrictPageFilter.doFilter(RestrictPageFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.pdinh.bizsim.presentation.filter.CustomCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CustomCharacterEncodingFilter.java:20)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID frmMain:bossMeeting:j_id2 has already been found in the view.  
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:846)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.saveView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:144)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:419)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.pdinh.bizsim.presentation.filter.RestrictPageFilter.doFilter(RestrictPageFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.pdinh.bizsim.presentation.filter.CustomCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CustomCharacterEncodingFilter.java:20)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

code: I'm trying to add a h:graphicImage tag to the f:facets footer tag but I get an error

```
<p:panelGrid columns="1">
            <f:facet
                name="header"
                style="right:0px">
                <h:outputText value="#{bossMeetingViewBean.currentSlide.title}" />
            </f:facet>
            <pdinh:editor
                value="#{bossMeetingViewBean.currentSlide.body}"
                width="800"
                height="300"
                id="slideBody" />
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <h:graphicImage value="#{resource['images/icons/exclamation_16x16.png']}" />
                <h:outputText value="Footer Text" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: The error is indicating that an element with the generated id `frmMain:bossMeeting:j_id2` occurs more than once. I'm guessing that `frmMain` is a `h:form` element and `bossMeeting` is another container element. However none of these appear in your posted code.